# Is there a way to pass an argument to the `test` function of the `firstWhere` method of an iterable

Tags: dart, iterable

I am learning Dart and I'm following the [Codelabs tutorial on iterable collections](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#example-using-firstwhere).

I have just read about the `firstWhere` method of iterables for finding the first element that satisfies some criterion.

The tutorial gives an example similar to the following:

```
bool predicate(String item, {int minLength = 6}) => item.length > minLength;

void main() {
  const items = ['Salad', 'Popcorn', 'Toast', 'Lasagne'];
  var foundItem = items.firstWhere(predicate);
  print(foundItem);
}
```

Which would print `Popcorn` as it is the first string with 6 or more characters.

I'm wondering whether it is possible to pass the `minLength` argument to `predicate` when calling `items.firstWhere(predicate)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, but like this:

```dart
final minLength = 6;
final foundItem = items.firstWhere((String item) => item.length > minLength));
```

what you example is doing is just extracting the method `(String item) => item.length > minLength;` to a separate global variable. which isn't necessary and I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: Or: `final foundItem = items.firstWhere((item) => predicate(item, minLength: 6));`, if you want to use the existing function.